# Read an excel file using Apache Camel

Tags: java, excel, apache-camel

I am trying to read an Excel file using Apache Camel. For that I have found that we can use the CSV component:

```
https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/dataformats/csv-dataformat.html
```

For that I have created a simple route which reads a XLSX file from a folder. Then I am trying to print the content of of that Excel file and write to another folder, but the contents of the file are not getting printed. The route is as below:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.csv.CsvDataFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    
    public void configure() {
        
        CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat();
        csv.setFormat(CSVFormat.EXCEL);
        
        from("file://C://work//ei01//source")
            .unmarshal(csv)
            .log("Reached ${body}")
            .marshal(csv)
            .to("file://C://work//ei01//destination?fileName=test.xlsx");
    }
}
```

The pom.xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>sprng-boot-camel-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sprng-boot-camel-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-csv-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Can you please suggest me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you try to read a real Excel file (`.xlsx`). That does not work with the [CSV data format](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/dataformats/csv-dataformat.html).

The `CSVFormat.EXCEL` format is to read CSV files (`.csv`) exported from Excel. Because the CSV format is done quite different from product to product, Camel supports multiple "well-known" CSV formats. One of them is `CSVFormat.EXCEL`.

To read the native Excel format (I think it is a ZIP file that contains XML files), you need a library like [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Yes I use Apache POI but was seaching is there any other way to read .xlsx files in Apache Camel.